# Visualizating incorrect data using the stream filter in Java

Tags: java, csv, filter, java-stream

I have a CSV file of the stock exchange I am taking data from, reading it and printing it under certain conditions. One of the conditions under which I must display them is to display the lowest value of a share of each share. My code only shows the first record of each of the three stocks, and does not show the lowest value of these stocks. Where am I going wrong in my filtering using the filter?

My code

```java
private static void smallestPriceByStock(List<String> stocks) throws ParseException {
    List<StockPrice> stockPrices = new ArrayList<>();
    HashSet<String> stock = new HashSet<>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdfOriginal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfNovaData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        for (String s : stocks) {
            String[] array = a.split(",");
            String name = array[0];
            String date = array[1];
            Date dataOriginal = sdfOriginal.parse(date);
            float fechamento = Float.parseFloat(array[2]);
            long volume = Long.parseLong(array[3]);
            StockPrice stockPrice = new StockPrice(nome, dataOriginal, price, volume);
            stockPrices.add(stockPrice);
            Stock st = new Stock(name);
            st.addStockPrice(stockPrice);
            stock.add(st.getNome());

        }
        System.out.println("Menores fechamentos");
        List<Cotacao> cotas = new ArrayList<>();
        double smallestValue = 0;
        for(String a : acao) {
            for (Cotacao c : cotacoes) {
                if (c.getNome().contains(a)) {
                    smallestValue = cotacoes.stream()
                            .filter(x -> x.getNome() == a)
                            .mapToDouble(x -> x.getValue()).summaryStatistics().getMax();
                        System.out.println("Stock: " + c.getNome() + ", " + "Price: " + smallestValue + ", " + "Date: " + sdfNovaData.format(c.getData()));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        for(Cotacao cotacao : cotas){
            System.out.println(cotacao.getNome());
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | ParseException e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("calculaMenorFechamentoPorAcao não implementado", e);
    }
}
```

A little sample of the CSV file:

```csv
Acao,Data,Fechamento,Volume
OGXP3,2013-01-01,4.38,0
OGXP3,2013-01-02,4.76,45904000
OGXP3,2013-01-03,4.90,38143400
PETR4,2013-01-02,19.69,30182600
PETR4,2013-01-03,20.40,30552600
PETR4,2013-01-04,20.43,36141000
PETR4,2013-01-07,20.08,28069600
VALE5,2013-01-01,40.87,0
VALE5,2013-01-02,42.60,18515700
VALE5,2013-01-03,42.09,15001800
VALE5,2013-01-04,41.36,26351900
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Unfortunately no, still having the incorrect visualization

Answer (score 0):

You are making this more complicated that it needs to be. The common pseudo code for finding lowest value is:

```
set lowestValue to null
for each value
   if lowestValue == null || value < lowestValue
       lowestValue = value
```

As you have multiple values to look for, each identified by the stock name, you define lowest_value as `Map<String, BigDecimal>` where the key is the stock identifier. Once you have processed each line in the input data, the map contains the lowest value for each stock. There is no need for nested loops, as everyting is done during the single pass. Once the you have populated the map, you can do the printing in a separate single loop over the map data.